# Why is_file shows different results in apache and cli environment

Tags: php

Why is_file shows different results in apache and cli environment on the same server, if I try to check the existence of a file with space in its name on a CIFS share? From console it shows that file exists, but if I run the same file under Apache the file is not found.

Comment: The path is correct. It seems that I need somehow to escape the white space. I have tried to put a backspace, but that did not help.

Comment: The path is /var/www/Tickets/20231104183000/used/Ticket_ 2023110400131.pdf, where /var/www/Tickets is a cifs share

Comment: If the user doesn't have permission to access this file, is_file also returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that was a permission problem.